# using browsers viewport size in an if statement

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have found the following javascript code to get the current viewport size

```
//get viewport size
var viewport = function(){
var viewport = new Object();
viewport.width = 0;
viewport.height = 0;
// the more standards compliant browsers (mozilla/netscape/opera/IE7) 
//use window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight
if (typeof window.innerWidth != 'undefined')
{
    viewport.width = window.innerWidth,
    viewport.height = window.innerHeight
}
else if (typeof document.documentElement != 'undefined'
&& typeof document.documentElement.clientWidth !=
'undefined' && document.documentElement.clientWidth != 0)
{
    viewport.width = document.documentElement.clientWidth,
    viewport.height = document.documentElement.clientHeight
}
else
{
    viewport.width = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientWidth,
    viewport.height = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientHeight
}
return viewport;
};

var vp = viewport();
alert(vp.width + " x " + vp.height);
```

which works great, but i want to know if it is possible to run a php if statement to display a specified number of items based on the view port size?

something like

```
if(vp > 480 x 700)
{
    $items = 4;
}
else
{
    $items = 2;
}
```

i know vp can't be used in this way but if anyone knows of a way i can use the value of vp in php i'd really appreciate some help :)

Many Thanks
Luke

Comment: I don't think you pass variables values between javascript and PHP. What you can do which is pretty simple is to bridge between using cookies. ie in your js script when you get the height and width of the viewport set the cookies and then read them in PHP and do whatever.

Comment: ah thats a good idea, will give that a shot. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

PHP runs on the server, JavaScript on the client. To get informations passed you have to, well, pass the information. This means send a message.

To do that you have many different ways that depend on the context:

- During page load?
  Well, transmit (i.e.: create) a small HTML or PHP page where the client runs that code and then the JavaScript redirects itself to a new page - and there you can pass the value as an URL parameter
- After page load and the page shouldn't be reloaded?

  - Using the latest web features?
    You could try web sockets
  - Staying a bit more conservative?
    You should use an AJAX request.

Oh, and one more thing to consider: PHP scripts are typically run in a Request-Response way. I.e. that can't wait for a user feedback during sending the page content.
So you might also need a way to track the user, e.g. by a session ID.